# Return multiple values from a function

Tags: r, function

I have a generic function which I want to get three values from. However it only returns one of the values from the "return" function. My code is structured like this:

```
doEverythingFunction <- function(x){

    "do some esoteric calculations here"
    return(valueX)
    "do some more esoteric calculations here"
    return(valueY)
    "do even more esoteric calculations here"
    return(valueZ)
}
```

This function only returns value Z and not X and Y. How can I get it to return all three values?

Comment: `return(list(valueX, valueY, valueZ)))`

Comment: Just do one return at the end as `return(list(valueX, valueY, valueZ))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In R you can only return one object. You could put the three values in a list or a vector and then return that list or vector.